# opencv-python imshow giving errors in mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I installed opencv-python using pip install, in mac os. Now the cv2.imshow function giving following error

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage

How can I solve this issue? Why doesn't the pip check opencv dependencies?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue. :(

Comment: @SwaathiKakarla Did you find a sol?

Comment: Sorry unable to find any solution yet, probably install from source is an option.

Comment: Did you try placing `cv2.waitKey()` function after `cv2.imshow()` ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems launching imshow windows doesn't work when installing opencv-python from pypi. Instead remove that and follow the great instructions at http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/

(Note that no longer need to use --HEAD tag, as of 3.2.0)

In short:

- Ensure Xcode installed
- brew tap homebrew/science
- brew install opencv3 --with-contrib
- echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> (YOUR PYTHONPATH)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opencv3.pth

Comment: After installing with brew it says what commands should be perform for python bindings. In my case these 3 did the job:
1) echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opencv3.pth
2)mkdir -p /Users/___XXX___yourHomeDir___XXX___/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
3)echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/___XXX___yourHomeDir___XXX___/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked best for me was using **mathplotlib** instead.

Since you may have to remove all previous versions of OpenCV otherwise and reinstall from source!

Comment: The post is 7 months old, the poster probably moved to something else. Recommending him to rewrite a project is not either an accurate answer for other users facing similar issues.